# How should we celebrate Gardening & Landscaping's 10 year anniversary?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Gardening & Landscaping will be turning 10 years old in a couple of months, along with some other sites in the network, and Stack Exchange is hoping to celebrate this milestone with:

- a blog post commemorating the 10 year anniversary of the sites that hit 10 years in the next few months. They're asking for a couple of paragraphs from us with a brief history of the community, and a description of what makes this community special.
- a "10 Year Anniversary" banner at the top of every page on the site. This is voluntary, only sites that opt in will have it.

This post is more about getting a sense of people's interest in celebrating the 10 year anniversary. If it seems like the community is in favor of joining in, I'll do another post asking for ideas for the blog post.